# Why are the tabs squeezed together and does not change colour?

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a dynamic tab with PHP and MySQL using the Bootstrap Framework.

I am wondering why the dynamic tab is squeezed together. In addition, when I click the tab, it does not change color to show that I clicked that tab.

**Actual Result:**
The tabs 'Now Showing' and 'Coming Soon' are squeezed together. The selected tab does not change color even when it is clicked.
[image: Actual Result]

**Expected Result:**
The tabs 'Now Showing' and 'Coming Soon' should not be squeezed together. When either of the tab is clicked, that particular tab should change color.
[image]

How do I solve this problem such that the tabs will not be squeezed together AND the tabs will change color when it is clicked (to differentiate it from the tabs that are not clicked ---> as shown in the Expected Result)

Here are my codes:

```
<?php

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'movie';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$tab_query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY Category_ID";
$tab_result = mysqli_query($conn, $tab_query);
$tab_menu = '';
$count = 0;


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tab_result)) {
    if ($count == 0) {
        $tab_menu .= '<li class="active"><a href="#' . $row["Category_ID"] . '" data-toggle="tab">' . $row["Category_Name"] . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        $tab_menu .= '<li><a href="#' . $row["Category_ID"] . '" data-toggle="tab">' . $row["Category_Name"] . '</a></li>';
    }
    $count++;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Movie Website</title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">

        <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"    integrity=   
              "sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!--Custom CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <!--jQuery-->
        <script defer 
                src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"  
                integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="  
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!--Bootstrap JS--> 
        <script defer   
                src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"    
                integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm"  
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script defer src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include "nav.inc.php"; ?> 
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <?php echo $tab_menu; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkmqncXTiLU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure and classes for `.tabs` is:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Looks like you missed some classes.

The `active` class needs to go to `<a>` tag and the `<li>` tag needs a class `nav-item`. This will make it work. So it should essentially be:

```php
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tab_result)) {
    if ($count == 0) {
        $tab_menu .= '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#' . $row["Category_ID"] . '" data-toggle="tab">' . $row["Category_Name"] . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        $tab_menu .= '<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#' . $row["Category_ID"] . '" data-toggle="tab">' . $row["Category_Name"] . '</a></li>';
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: this solved the problem of being squeezed together. thank you! however, the other tab is now invisible. For instance, if I click the 'Now Showing' tab, the Coming Soon tab cannot be seen (it can only be soon if you mouse hover).

Comment: @user14489561 Oh, that's bad. Do you wanna show the output generated HTML on https://JSBin.com or https://CodePen.io or https://CodeSandbox.io and share me here? I can help fix it. Again it should be a mismatch of class names.

Comment: hi @praveen i have shared my codes on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910880/the-dynamic-tabs-are-presenting-the-same-records